# Laravel 5.6: Copy of downloaded file in public folder

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I access to the route of this function:

```
public function storephp($id)
{
$fileText = "file.php";
$content = 
"test content"

file_put_contents($fileText, $content);
return Response::download($fileText);
}
```

With this I can download the file, no problem with that. But every time I download the file there is a copy in the public folder. I mean, If I downloaded the file.php file three times, there is one file.php file in the public folder. I would like to know if this is normal and if not how I can solve it.

Comment: actually latest file replaces the previous file with same name. you can also try different name in different time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the file every time by `file_put_contents`. You can use:

```
Response::download($fileText)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

OR

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () use($content) {
    echo $content;
}, 'file.php');
```

In the second method, delete the `file_put_contents` line